# How to match similar groups that repeat, but aren't the same

Tags: regex

I have a number of strings relating to products. Each of these have reference numbers and I want to create a regex that picks up if different reference numbers are mentioned more than one time. So, given the following example:

```
"AB01 MyProduct" >>> No match - because there is only one ID
"AB02 MyOtherProduct" >>> No match - because there is only one ID
"AB03 YetAnotherProduct" >>> No match - because there is only one ID
"AnAccessory for AB01, AB02, AB03 or AB101" >>> Matches!!
"AB02 MyOtherProduct, MyOtherProduct called the AB02" >>> No match - because the codes are the same
```

Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Do the IDs always start with `AB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex engine supports [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), this would do the trick:

```
(AB\d+).*?(?!\1)AB\d+
```

It matches if there are two sequences matching `AB\d+` and the second one is not the same as the first one (ensured by the negative lookahead).

Explained:

```
(           # start capture group 1
 AB         # match `AB` literally
 \d+        # match one or more digits
)           # end capture group one
.*?         # match any sequence of characters, non-greedy
(?!         # start negative lookahead, match this position if it does not match
 \1         # whatever was captured in capture group 1
)           # end lookahead
AB          # match `AB` literally
\d+         # match one or more digits
```

Tests (JavaScript):

```
> var pattern = /(AB\d+).*?(?!\1)AB\d+/;
> pattern.test("AB01 MyProduct")
  false
> pattern.test("AnAccessory for AB01, AB02, AB03 or AB101")
  true
> pattern.test("AB02 MyOtherProduct, MyOtherProduct called the AB02")
  false
```